# Cannot convert input to Timestamp, bday_range(...) - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to generate a number for the days in business days between current date and the end of the month of a pandas dataframe. 
E.g. 26/06/2017 - 4, 23/06/2017 - 5

I'm having trouble as I keep getting a Type Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
```

From line:

```
result['bdaterange'] = pd.bdate_range(pd.to_datetime(result['dte'], unit='ns').values, pd.to_datetime(result['bdate'], unit='ns').values)
```

I have a Data Frame result with the column dte in a date format and I'm trying to create a new column (bdaterange) as a simple integer/float that I can use to see how far from month end in business days it has.

```
Sample data:
           bid   ask  spread         dte        day      bdate
01:49:00  2.17  3.83    1.66  2016-12-20  20.858333 2016-12-30
02:38:00   2.2   3.8    1.60  2016-12-20  20.716667 2016-12-30
22:15:00  2.63  3.12    0.49  2016-12-20  21.166667 2016-12-30
03:16:00  1.63  2.38    0.75  2016-12-21  21.391667 2016-12-30
07:11:00  1.46  2.54    1.08  2016-12-21  21.475000 2016-12-30
```

I've tried `BDay()` and using that the day cannot be 6 & 7 in the calculation but have not got anywhere. I came across `bdate_range` which I believe will be exactly what I'm looking for, but the closest I've got gives me the error `Cannot convert input to Timestamp`.

My attempt is:

```
result['bdate'] = pd.to_datetime(result['dte']) + BMonthEnd(0)

result['bdaterange'] = pd.bdate_range(pd.to_datetime(result['dte'], unit='ns').values, pd.to_datetime(result['bdate'], unit='ns').values)

print(result['bdaterange'])
```

Not sure how to solve the error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need length of [`bdate_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.bdate_range.html) for each row, so need custom function with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
#convert only once to datetime
result['dte'] = pd.to_datetime(result['dte'])

f = lambda x: len(pd.bdate_range(x['dte'], x['dte'] + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0)))
result['bdaterange'] = result.apply(f, axis=1)
print (result)
           bid   ask  spread        dte        day  bdaterange
01:49:00  2.17  3.83    1.66 2016-12-20  20.858333           9
02:38:00  2.20  3.80    1.60 2016-12-20  20.716667           9
22:15:00  2.63  3.12    0.49 2016-12-20  21.166667           9
03:16:00  1.63  2.38    0.75 2016-12-21  21.391667           8
07:11:00  1.46  2.54    1.08 2016-12-21  21.475000           8
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks.
Why did it have to use a len() function instead of values?

Comment: I think there in each row get output `bdate_range`, what is `array` (`Datetimeindex`). and simplier get length of array is `len`